# Segfault on fprintf with a (supposedly) valid FILE pointer

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

So in this pretty large source file I have the following section, let's say in function `foo`, which is called from `main`:

```
FILE *logfile = NULL
if (log_engabled) {
    char fname[30];
    snprintf(fname, 30, ".logs/%d.txt", time(NULL));
    logfile = fopen(fname, "w");
}
fprintf(logfile, "test\n");
```

This executes without issues. (Yes, I should guard against `logfile == NULL` but I omitted that for brevity). In my test runs, `log_file == 0x840fa50` and `&log_file == 0x7ffffffedca8`.

I then call another function, `bar` which takes a bunch of arguments, including `FILE **log_stream`. Its body looks as such:

```
if (*log_stream)
    fprintf(*log_stream, "test\n");
/*a bunch of other stuff, including more fprintf calls*/
```

Now here's the weird part. If I call `bar` from `foo` directly after the above code segment, everything runs smoothly. However, at a later point in `foo`, `bar` is called again, with other parameters, but the same `logfile` pointer. Then I get a `SIGSEGV` right at the `fprintf` call. I checked with gdb, and the location of the pointer is exactly the same, as well as the value it points to (and I never call `fclose` in between).

What could be causing this behaviour? It must have to do with the code I'm running in between the calls to `bar`, but none of these statements include `logfile` in anything other than `fprintf` calls.

Maybe I cause the segfault somewhere other than the `fprintf` call and gdb gives me the wrong line number, but I compiled with gcc -O0 and -g, and when I move the print statement around, so does the error indication.

I also tried declaring `logfile` as a global variable and not passing it to `bar`, to no avail. Any help is appreciated here.

**EDIT:**

I did some digging around and *drum roll* - The problem was caused by an unsigned integer underflow causing an out of range array write. More Concretely:

```
foo() {
    FILE *logfile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    fprintf(logfile, "test1");
    memory_corrupting_function();
    fprintf(logfile, "test2");
}
```

The first `fprintf` goes smoothly again, and the second triggers a `SIGSEGV`. So, to rephrase my original question: Seeing how the programs continues to execute just fine if I don't call `fprintf` again, why would the segfault occur when I call `fprintf` and not when I write to an invalid memory location?

Is there even an answer or is it just undefined behaviour that changes across implementations?

Comment: Can you please try to create an [mcve] to show us?

Comment: Is `logfile` a local var in some function?

Comment: Also, why are you passing a pointer to the variable? what's the purpose of that? Will the life-time of the variable `logfile` be valid throughout the call to your function? Passing a `FILE**` seems very suspect and makes warning bells ring for me.

Comment: Try -Wall and especially -Wimplicit-function-declaration and your problem should be revealed.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I will try to create MCVE in about 5 hours. `logfile` is local to `foo` only. Initially I passed just `FILE*` but got worried that the initial pointer might have to be referenced.
I always compile with -Wall -Wextra and get no warnings.

Comment: How did you print the value `logfile`?

Comment: For the new question (which should really be posted as a proper new question) it's because of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the address of a local variable. Most likely, `logfile` will exist on the stack. Once, `foo` returns, there is a very good chance that whatever value `logfile` held will be overwritten. The file pointer returned by `fopen()` will remain valid until you `fclose()` the file. But the variable `logfile` will go out of scope once the function returns.

Just return the value of `logfile`:

```
FILE * foo() {
    FILE *logfile = NULL;
    //....
    return logfile;
}

void bar() {
    FILE *alsoLogfile = foo();
    // ...
}
```

In your question you state: *If I call bar from foo directly after the above code segment, everything runs smoothly.* This is most likely happening because the part of the stack where `logfile` existed had not been overwritten yet. Using the address of an out-of-scope variable is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: @R.. I'm partly guessing here as the question is a bit incomplete (i.e. the prototype for `foo()` is missing).